# Cyclical time series classification with missing data

Tags: time-series, bayesian, classification, missing-data

I have a time series binary classification problem.

Each datapoint is an **evenly-spaced, equal length time series**, representing one full week of hourly measurements, where I expect to see strong daily patterns (think: human behaviour). For example, presence and magnitude of peaks on given weekdays should be strongly predictive of a class (but I expect some other, more subtle features to be predictive as well).

I considered a few techniques that could work, like dynamic time warping, or bag of features. The main issue is that **many samples (during both training and inference) have data gaps**, sometimes of considerable size (e.g. full day of data missing). Discarding these samples is not an option. To use algorithms like kNN+DTW, I would need to impute the missing data, which would lead to incorrect results (e.g. simple interpolation may create fake plateaus, ARIMA may create fake peaks, etc.).

My ideal solution would be to have a **probability** of belonging to each class, such that data gaps would add uncertainty, instead of invalidating the results (some sort of Bayesian algorithm?), but I'm interested in any useful suggestions.

**Question**: What would be a recommended way of dealing with such problems? Is there any standard solution to this?

Comment: How many weakly time series? How many classes? What **is** the classes? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Let's say the training data is around a hundred of datapoints per class (one datapoint = time series representing one week). There are actually multiple classification problems I'm interested in, but e.g. I might want to ask if it was summer or winter, what was the subject's gender, if the subject is following certain routine or not, etc. My question is about binary classification problem, though other cases are also interesting to me.

Comment: Please add this extra info to the post as an edit, not everybody reads comments. [Many similar posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time-ser*+classi*+answers%3A1).

Comment: Do some of this [earlier posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time-ser*+classific*+answers%3A1) help?

Comment: Thank you for the comments @kjetilbhalvorsen! I searched through those posts before asking my question. I'm aware of time series classification methods in general. As I emphasized in my question, my specific problem is the missing data, which I cannot easily interpolate, impute, or drop. None of the other questions I've seen gives an answer to this problem.